# Use the SQL file as data repository for React Native data

Tags: sql, react-native

I just want to ask if there's a way to use the .sql file inside your app folder to be loaded in your React Native app and use it as the source of all of your data? Thank you very much!

[Sample Image with SQL File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VSaD.png)

Comment: That file contains SQL commands, not data. You used the `MySQL` tag which means you have a MySQL server installed somewhere.

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: SQL does not run in the browser. It's of absolutely no use to React. This must be done server-side.

Comment: @tadman well, this is not entirely correct, SQLite has a javascript version that does run in web browsers.

Comment: @Shadow Worth noting, though I'm not sure it's exactly what's desired here. SQLite isn't MySQL compatible.

Comment: @tadman this is why I provided it as a comment and not as an answer. The OP needs to clarify the situation.

Comment: Guess I have to use SQLite rather than mySQL. Thanks for the tip guys!